# IIS - redirecting from localhost:8001/name/secondName/ to wcf service url

Tags: wcf, iis

question like in title - I have wcf service on localhost:8001 but I want it also accessible from localhost:8001/name/secondName/
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with URL rewriting. You need to add this rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Rewrite /name/secondName" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^name/secondName(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```